# Define a structure in python to use a function from a C library (dll)

Tags: python, dll, data-structures, header, ctypes

For beginning, sorry for my english.

I have some trouble to use a function from a dynamic library (the gnu gsl library) in a Python script.

Indeed, I know use a function but I need to define a Structure white C type datas to use a particulary function.

In first this is an example of the use of the function in a C++ script that I would use in Python script:

```
    double fn1 (double x, void * params)
{
    return cos(x) + 1.0;
}
int
main (void)
{
       gsl_min_fminimizer *s;
       double m = 2.0, m_expected = M_PI;
       double a = 0.0, b = 6.0;
       gsl_function F;

       F.function = &fn1;
       F.params = 0;

       T = gsl_min_fminimizer_brent;
       s = gsl_min_fminimizer_alloc (T);
       gsl_min_fminimizer_set (s, &F, m, a, b);

       ...
}
```

The typedef of gsl_function in the header is:

```
struct gsl_function_struct 
{
  double (* function) (double x, void * params);
  void * params;
};

typedef struct gsl_function_struct gsl_function ;

#define GSL_FN_EVAL(F,x) (*((F)->function))(x,(F)->params)
```

I know use a function with ctypes:

```
#Library Call

lib_gsl=CDLL(path_gsl+"gsl.dll")

#Functions Define

gsl_opti_brent=lib_gsl.gsl_min_fminimizer_brent
gsl_opti_alloc=lib_gsl.gsl_min_fminimizer_alloc
gsl_opti_init=lib_gsl.gsl_min_fminimizer_set

T=gsl_opti_brent
T_=pointer(T)
s=gsl_opti_alloc(T_)
```

Until this, there is no trouble but when I want use the function gsl_min_fminimizer_set, I need a particulary type define in a header called gsl_function.

There is somebody knows how can I define the typedef gsl_function in Python to use the dll called function gsl_min_fminimizer_set?

Thank you. 
I expect I am explicit

Comment: Did you have a look at [PyGSL](http://pygsl.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [this](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) ctypes tutorial (specially Structures and Callback functions).

It should be something like this:

```
MY_FUNC_TYPE = CFUNCTYPE(c_double, c_double, c_void_p)
class GSL_FUNCTION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("function", MY_FUNC_TYPE),
                ("params", c_void_p)]

def py_fn1(x, params):
    return cos(x) + 1.0

fn1 = MY_FUNC_TYPE(py_fn1)

F = GSL_FUNCTION(fn1, 0)
```

Comment: It's maybe an other error but The result is: WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000  But it is difficult to know where is my error so I try to install the interface pygsl. This is no easier than I thinked...

Comment: For information I have an other question about the installation of pygsl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007000/installation-of-pygsl-on-windows-library-pyd-not-find-by-python

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `ctypes.Structure`. Here is a way to create structs in python;

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class POINT(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
...                 ("y", c_int)]
...
>>> point = POINT(10, 20)
>>> print point.x, point.y
10 20
```

For more examples you can check out [ctypes documentation.](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions)